# how do i get form model on clicking the add button using angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, ngx-bootstrap

### company.html

```html
   

     <section class="main">
      <h1>Company Management</h1>
         <md-card class="mat-card">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>
 
        <md-card-title class="md-title mat-card-title">
          <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 title">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Username</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Type</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Active</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Action</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content class="md-content mat-card-content">
          <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>Hotel</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>hotel@gmail.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span>company</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <button class="iconBtn">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </button>
              <button class="iconBtn">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </section>

    <ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" 
    (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

### company.component.ts

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'; 
import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './company.html'
})
export class CompanyComponent {

}
export class DemoModalServiceStaticComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule{

}
```

here,
i need to display a form(kind of popup box) on clicking the add_button(+) but it is not displaying anything after tapping on that add_button(+)
how do i get form model on clicking the add button using angular2 ???
( Example: i'm expecting like a popup box display after click on the add_button[+] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import ElementRef &ViewChild from '@angular/core' if you want to access your #template you simply have to create a viewchild variable :

```
@ViewChild("template") template: ElementRef;
```

and then you can access it using this.template which has many value.

Then if you want to access a form into a modal, you can also add a #form to your form and then access this.modal.form

Comment: export class CompanyComponent {
  @ViewChild('template') template: ElementRef;

    showChildModal(): void {
    this.template.show();
  }
 
  hideChildModal(): void {
    this.template.hide();
  }
}                          like this i tried but getting compilation error as " Cannot find name 'ElementRef'"

Comment: check this plunkr http://embed.plnkr.co/NEeEPfkHsYBbVuuAxz5z/ in this case he is using another component instead of an ElementRef. But in your case you don't have <app-component #componentAccess></app-component> Don't forget to Import ViewChild & ElementRef from core !!

Comment: Last comment to fix your problem : create another modal component you can use anywhere on your website <app-modal #modal></app-modal> in your parent html code. Then you will be able to manage the modal behavior as an individual component. If you don't do that, you will not be able to access an elementRef function (because it's a DOM element).
If you keep your code, then add *ngIf="displayModal" in your html div element and control it in your parent directly.

<button (click)="displayModal = true"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) which provides all bootstrap javascript components without writing any jQuery in your component.

[Here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) is a full tutorial how to implement modal in your app.

Comment: i made ngx-bootstrap instalation and changed the code as mentioned in the link but now also i'm not getting any modal display after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed  **data-target="#myModal"**  property on add button. Please add it and then check.

Comment: '<button aria-label="New Task" class="md-fab md-mini add-task mat-mini-fab" md-mini-fab="" mdtooltip="Add" mdtooltipposition="below" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'

Comment: i had included that in the button tag but no changes in the output is there any need to include(install)  kind of modal_files related to it?

Comment: Did you include bootstrap js and css files properly?